# Restarting a CountDownTimer in a Dialog window after an OnTouchEvent in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener, touch-event, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer that dismisses a dialog popup window. I would like for this timer to restart if the user touches the screen. Here is what I have so far,

```
public class dataCapture extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
...
MotionEvent event;
View.OnTouchListener touchListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedDataEntryInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedDataEntryInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
...
@Override
public View onCreateView
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnHelpFilexml:
            openHelpDialog();
            break;
        ...
    }

private void openHelpDialog() {
    Button btnCloseWindow;
    final Dialog helpDialog;
    TextView tvHelpDialogTitle, tvHelpDialogBody;
    helpDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    helpDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    helpDialog.setCancelable(true);
    helpDialog.setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog);

    tvHelpDialogTitle = (TextView) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpDialogTitle);
    tvHelpDialogTitle.setText("DataCapture Help");

    tvHelpDialogBody = (TextView) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpDialogBody);
    tvHelpDialogBody.setText("Start of help text\n" +
            "This is help text\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Here we go...\n" +
            ...
            "This is the end.");

    btnCloseWindow = (Button) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCloseWindow);
    btnCloseWindow.setText("Close");

    btnCloseWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        // new countDownTimer(30000, 1000) {//makes popup go away after 30 secs
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {//Do something every second...
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {//action at end of specified time
            helpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.start();
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    helpDialog.show();
  }
}
```

Any suggestions regarding how best to implement this function would be highly appreciated. Copious TIA.

**UPDATE** Got it. Solution below. Thanks.

```
public class dataCapture extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
...
private static final int COUNTDOWN_TIME_MS = 30000;
Handler handlerHelpDialogTimer;
Runnable runnableHelpDialogDismissCountdown;
Dialog helpDialog;

 private Dialog getHelpDialog() {
    Button btnCloseWindow;
    final Dialog helpDialog;
    TextView tvHelpDialogTitle, tvHelpDialogBody;
    helpDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    helpDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    helpDialog.setCancelable(true);
    helpDialog.setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog);
    tvHelpDialogTitle = (TextView) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvHelpDialogTitle);
    tvHelpDialogTitle.setText("DataCapture Help");
    tvHelpDialogBody.setText("Start of help text\n" +
        "This is help text\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Wheee, here we go\n" +
        ...
        "this is the end.");
    btnCloseWindow = (Button) helpDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCloseWindow);
    btnCloseWindow.setText("Close");
    btnCloseWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    tvHelpDialogBody.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View tvHelpDialogBody, MotionEvent event) {
            cancelCountdown();
            startCountdown();
            return false;
        }
    });
    helpDialog.show();
    return (helpDialog);
}
private void showHelpDialog() {
    helpDialog = getHelpDialog();
    helpDialog.show();
    startCountdown();
}
synchronized private void startCountdown() {
    handlerHelpDialogTimer.postDelayed(getCountdownTask(), COUNTDOWN_TIME_MS);
}
synchronized private void cancelCountdown() {
    handlerHelpDialogTimer.removeCallbacks(runnableHelpDialogDismissCountdown);
    runnableHelpDialogDismissCountdown = null;
}
private Runnable getCountdownTask() {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (helpDialog != null) helpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    runnableHelpDialogDismissCountdown = task;
    return task;
}
```

Comment: I used getHelpDialog in the code example because I was assuming you may want different instances of the dialog in case you end up dismissing it. That is, you'd only call getHelpDialog whenever you needed to show it again. Calling `return(getHelpDialog())` is not a good idea as a recursive, endless loop. Instead, you'd call it when you want to call show; setting it to the class's field member `helpDialog` and nullifying `helpDialog` when it is dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the countdown timer. Instead use a handler, for example:

```
public class AwesomeActivity extends Activity {

  private static final int COUNTDOWN_TIME_MS = 300000;
  Handler handler;
  Runnable countDown;
  Dialog helpDialog;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    handler = new Handler();
  }

  /* call cancelCountdown() in onPause*  */

  private Dialog getHelpDialog() { return /* fill in the details */ }

  private void showHelpDialog() { 
    helpDialog = getHelpDialog();
    helpDialog.show();
    startCountDown();
  } 

  synchronized private void startCountDown() {
    handler.postDelayed(getCountdownTask(), COUNTDOWN_TIME_MS);
  } 

  synchronized private void cancelCountdown() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(countdown);
    countdown = null;
  }

 private Runnable getCountdownTask() {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        if (helpDialog != null) helpDialog.dismiss();
      }
    };
    countDown = task;
    return task;
  } 
}
```

Now in `onTouch(MotionEvent e)` you can cancel and start the countdown.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to handle `onPause` and `onResume` :)

Furthermore, if you really wanted to, you could override a `Dialog` and put the `Handler` timer countdown logic inside that class, overriding `show()` to start the countdown and then add a method such as, `restartTimer()` you can call after a `TOUCH_DOWN`. If you do, you can then also override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` in the `Dialog` subclass, to cancel the callback, stash the time remaining, then pull out the time remaining and re-postdelay the countdown runnable with the remaining time.